# Join + group by, then filter group rows that contain "x" and not "y"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get results from two tables by using an inner join. The condition is that I need to check that the other table column must have the value "xyz" but must not have the value "abc".

Table A:

| id | column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | row1 |
| 2 | row 2 |

Table B:

| id | Aid | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | xyz |
| 2 | 1 | abc |
| 3 | 2 | xyz |

I've tried below query:

```
SELECT a.id as a_id
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN B as b  ON b.Aid = a.id 
WHERE b.status='xyz' AND b.status!='abc'
GROUP BY a.id
```

But it returns both ids 1 and 2 but it must return id 2 only.

Please help me with an example that is done with joins and where condition only rather than using having and subqueries.

Comment: Is (aid,status) unique?

Comment: @Strawberry that is of enum type

Comment: That's not what I asked :-(

Comment: @Strawberry yes they are unique

Comment: Why not just `b.status='xyz'` the extra criteria is not necessary

Comment: @ChrisSchaller there will be a case if the status is having other value too like "qrs" so i need to take that condition too.

Comment: @JanezKuhar I need to do it via using joins only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ids `1` and `2` are correctly returned because both of them are linked to records in `B` that have a status of `'xyz'`.

If what you want is to exclude the results where the joined table includes any record that has 'abc' then we have to get a little bit cleverer.

In MS SQL, we can use a simple case expression to turn your filters into numeric states, this is similar to pivoting the data:

```
SELECT a.id as a_id, COUNT(expr.IsABC)
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN B as b  ON b.Aid = a.id 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IsXYZ = CASE WHEN status = 'xyz' THEN 1 END, IsABC = CASE WHEN status = 'abc' then 1 END) as expr
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(expr.IsXYZ) > 0 AND COUNT(expr.IsABC) = 0
```

What you are really asking is this:

> return the Ids from `A` where they have at least one related status in `B` that is `'xyz'` but must not have any record in `B` with a status of `'abc'`

This can also be achieved with a nested query:
*This is valid in MySQL - [see this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a9f03/4)*

```
SELECT a_id
FROM (
    SELECT a.id as a_id, CASE WHEN status = 'xyz' THEN 1 END as IsXYZ, CASE WHEN status = 'abc' then 1 END as IsABC
    FROM A as a
    INNER JOIN B as b  ON b.Aid = a.id 
) as projection
GROUP BY a_id
HAVING COUNT(IsXYZ) > 0 AND COUNT(IsABC) = 0;
```

Or you could us a `NOT EXISTS` style query:  [(fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a9f03/8)

```
SELECT a.id as a_id
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN B as b ON b.Aid = a.id 
WHERE status = 'xyz' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT b2.id FROM B as b2 WHERE b2.AId = a.Id AND b2.status = 'abc')
GROUP BY a_id;
```

---

### NOTE:

In this contrived example there is no need to event join on Table `A` at all, you could do this entirely from Table `B`

```
SELECT Aid
FROM B
GROUP BY Aid
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'xyz' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'abc' then 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: can you please help me with an example that is done with joins and where condition only rather than using having and subqueries

Comment: Updated with a MySQL version for you to test @JashanPabla

Comment: I want it to be done with inner joins and where condition only.

Comment: Can we ask why? The only other way is to self join, but that is effectively the same query plan as a sub query... I'll put one of those together too, but it sounds like there is a lot more to this story than is being provided

Comment: Either way, you need two separate comparison sets, so you must use either a window query, CTE, non correleated sub-query (NOT EXISTS) , non-correlated join (OUTER JOIN and omit the matches) or a HAVING clause. This type of query is explicitly what `HAVING` is designed to support

Answer (score 0):

There is a record fitting to "b.status='xyz' AND b.status!='abc'" in the group of Records with id 1. Therefore you also get returned the id 1. If you try to relate the records in B against each other you must do a self-join in B.

```
SELECT b1.Aid FROM B b1
WHERE b1.status='xyz' 
   AND not exists 
   (select b2.id from B b2 where b2.Aid = b1.Aid and b2.status = 'abc')
```

Comment: Getting both id's with this query too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your condition ( `b.status = 'xyz' and b.status != 'abc'` ) in each group, not globally. You can do that using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT a.id AS a_id
FROM A AS a
INNER JOIN B AS b
ON b.aid = a.id 
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.status) LIKE '%xyz%' AND
  GROUP_CONCAT(b.status) NOT LIKE '%abc%'
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=811d05412e71d0d0057257f198456e3e)